# How to troubleshoot 17.04 failure to boot after new installation with UEFI

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I created a 17.04 installer on a  GPT formatted USB with Startup Disk Creator and used it to create a new 17.04 installation on a GPT formatted SSD.The intent was that the new SSD should boot iin UEFI mode without Secure Boot.

When I boot from this SSD I simply get a blank screen with no indication that Grub2 has loaded or done anything. The system is not completely locked because I can reboot with Ctrl-Alt-Delete.

I have verified that there are no apparent hardware problems and both the installation USB and the new SSD pass a e2fsck check.

The new SSD has an ESP of 400Mb and the contents appear to be sensible.

How should I troubleshoot this situation? I want to both solve this specific problem and improve my troubleshooting skills with the latter being the priority.

Comment: Use boot-repair - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @bodi many people have said not to use boot repair on uefi

Comment: Advice to not use Boot Repair on UEFI systems is mostly very old. These days it works fairly well, although it's not guaranteed to work. Overall, bodhi.zazen's advice is sound. If that doesn't work, perhaps my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive or CD-R would get the system booted, at least temporarily until a more permanent solution could be arranged. (Using rEFInd on the hard disk might be such a solution, but something else might work, too.)

Comment: @Rod Smith If I use rEFind on the hard drive does this mean that I will need to add rEFind to the Iso image on my USB drive as well. Also would it best to make my USB drive boot using rEFind (it boots seemingly OK now).

Comment: I provide USB flash drive and CD-R images of rEFInd that can be used to boot Ubuntu (and other OS) installations on hard disk that fail to boot for a variety of reasons. This is intended as a temporary/emergency tool. If you choose to install rEFInd on your hard disk, it will take over as the default boot manager and enable you to boot without using GRUB. In neither case is it necessary to use rEFInd to boot OS installers on their own USB flash drives (although it *can* be used to do that).

Comment: @Rod Am I correct in understanding that your USB Flash rEFInd disk is a standalone boot image that brings up rEFInd to complete the boot process with a boot loader from the problematic hard drive?

Comment: Jonathan, yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @Rod which pointed me in the right direction, I was able to solve this problem. What happened was that my machine is 5+ years old and has an early copy of UEFI which seems to ignore the EFI boot order. Instead it insists that the ESP must be on /dev/sda1 and on my machine it was on /dev/sda3 as a result of numerous changes to disk configurations.

I needed to delete all the partitions on the disk, then delete the GPT partition itself. Once this was complete I then created a new set of partitions with the ESP as the first partition, landing on /dev/sda1. Finally I reinstalled Ubuntu 17.04, rebooted and everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

three specific difficulties come to mind immediately.

first: efi firmware stored information. If you have a ubuntu live image, start it and install efibootmgr. use it to remove all entries in the efi.

second: not all uefi implementations, scan for OS. They look for /efi/boot/bootx64.efi on the first fat32 partition. copy grubx64.efi to this folder and rename it.

Third: some efi implementions, require a 1 GB ntfs recovery or diagnostics partition to be the first thing on the disk with the efi partition being second.

Fourth: verify that you booted and installed uefi. some systems will boot CMS when secure boot is turned off

Comment: Most of this advice is poor. (1) Removing *all* EFI NVRAM boot entries causes some EFIs to flake out. Removing extra/unwanted entries may be worthwhile, but certainly not *all* of them. (2) AFAIK, *no* EFI implementations scan for OSes; they rely on entries in the NVRAM, although that's sometimes broken. (3) AFAIK, *no* EFI requires any NTFS volume. Many pre-installed systems come with such a partition, but it's not required by the EFI. (4) This is the best point, but it's Compatibility Support Module (CSM), not "CMS."

Comment: @Rod, (1) removing all forces it to use /efi/boot/bootx64.efi (this is the defalt inital  install mode) (2)yes, mine looks in all subdirectories in /efi/boot.  it lists my linux install. My computer also allows me to manually search for an efi file to boot (3) I have had 4 computers require a hidden recovery partition to be first on the internal drive.(4) Sorry confused with the BIOS addressing mode.

Comment: my experience in dealing with literally dozens of EFI-based computers is very different from yours. Note that I maintain the rEFInd boot manager, so I keep a close eye on this and understand the EFI boot process better than most. I strongly suspect that you're misinterpreting what's happened on your computers.

Comment: I am mot misunderstanding. the EFI specifically said, not a suitible boot device until I added the partition. I suspect this was a windows requirement of the manufacturer. the partition can be empty but it had to be there. and my first suggestion, has been required on almost all computers, especially dual boot, to keep windows from placing itself back in  the first position of the boot order.

Comment: @ravery my system (HP P7-1080la) came out before Secure boot was available so the Bios does not support it. Will this be a possible problem?

Comment: @Jonathan -- no secure boot? are you sure this is an uefi computer? as far as I know efi has always had secure boot. BOIS boot can not read gpt disks. double check your boot mode. this is likely the issue.

Comment: @ravery Secure Boot came out about a year after the original UEFI implementation and my machine is old enough to fall into that window. I have all kinds of evidence that it supports UEFI, both static from examining the Bios and dynamic through checking system status while the Ububtu LiveCD is running. Also the system populated the ESP during Ubuntu installation. If the system has Secure Boot there is no way of controlling it from the Bios.

Comment: @Jonathan -- can you turn off bios boot? how did you format the SSD? Linux does a non-destructive partitionig, thus  dual boot disk can be created (one that boots both efi and bios). if there is a MBR on the disk your system my be dropping to compatability mode and then not finding any MBR information.

Comment: @ravery There is a protective MBR on the disk. I know of no way to disable the bios boot. Do you? There is nothing in the Bios to support this.

Comment: @Jonathan -- if it can be disabled, it would be in the bios settings. is there an update available for the bios? you could try using windows to set up the SSD as gpt, of course this will delete all data. but might allow your computer to boot uefi. (windows does destructive partitioning)

Comment: Secure Boot is an *optional* UEFI feature, and there are (U)EFI-based computers without Secure Boot. All Intel-based Macs are among these, but there are others. Your description of the problem that led you to add NTFS partitions is extremely vague, ravery, so I can't comment further on it, but I'm virtually certain you're mistaken. Jonathan, a protective MBR is a necessary part of GPT; it is *not* a problem, if it's written correctly. Once again, I suggest you use Boot Repair or rEFInd. Mucking with your firmware settings is more likely than Boot Repair or rEFInd to create new problems.

Comment: @Rod In one sense I am lucky since my firmware has no accessible UEFI settings.